# Selective Loading in AggregatedView

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a viewer application that looks at published Revit-files on ACC. I am loading several nodes in an AggregatedView based on they belonging to a specific Location in ACC.

Sometimes the model might be published with a visible DWG or Revit link, which I do not want to load. I would like to use [Selective loading](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-feature-selective-loading), but I can't seem to make it work in my Aggregated View. Does anyone have just a small example of how to accomplish that?

I have tried implementing the blog post example in my code but I can't get the viewer to show the geometry.

Here's one example of something I've tried (bubbleoptions just searches for a specific view):

```
    const documentLoadOptions = 
{
    filter: {
        property_query: [
            {
                "$not": ["?Type Name", "'%Generic Models%'"]
            }
        ]

    } 
}
    export async function loadNode(item,documentLoadOptions,bubbleoptions) 
{
    var documentId = 'urn:' + item;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, (doc) => {
        var bubbleRoot = doc.getRoot().search(bubbleoptions);
        view.load(bubbleRoot[0],documentLoadOptions);
        view.show(bubbleRoot[0]);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    console.log("Loaded node: " + item);
}
```

I've tried different versions of calling loadDocumentNode (on view, and view.viewer) but haven't figured out what I'm doing wrong here. replacing view.load with view.viewer.loadDocumentNode doesn't give me errors but I'm not sure how to then trigger the AggregatedView to show the loaded models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the custom load options like this way:

```js
const options3d = {
    getCustomLoadOptions: (bubble, data) => {
        console.log(bubble, data);

        return {
            filter: {
                property_query: [{
                    "$not": ["?Type Name", "'%Generic Models%'"]
                }]

            }
        };
    }
};

view.init(viewerDiv, options3d);
```

ref: Please see `options` in https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/AggregatedView/#init-parentdiv-options

Comment: Thanks for the help Eason! I seem to be missing something, I have implemented your solution but It is still not filtering out the geometry. I'm initializing the viewer exactly like in your example (albeit with some more options in the options3d) and then adding bubbleNodes with AggregatedView.load(bubbleNode) and thewn showing them using AggregatedView.show(bubbleNode). I see the getCustomLoadOptions being called, and the filter looks good, but the data object is undentified, could that be messing with my implementation?

Comment: @Allmächd If so, I would advise you to check if the filter works in the simple viewer, not to use AggregatedView. I doubt that.

Comment: I have rebuilt it as a more simple viewer. I'm getting it to work and seems like the reason was the api version (derivativeV2 doesn't work with selective loading). I'm getting the selective loading to work but sadly using streamingV2 broke my DWGs that I am also loading. Working in that now, but I managed to solve the selective loading, thanks for the help Eason!

Comment: Selective Loading requires SVF2 models, so the api should be `streamingV2`. Is your CAD file a 2D DWG? If so, it's not SVF2.

Comment: They are 3D DWGs. It works completely fine when using derivativeV2, but I'm getting a "No Access. Sorry, you do not have the required privileges to access this item." popup and a 403 when using streamingV2 (everything else the same). I'm assuming I need to handle the loadDocumentNode differently for the DWGs in streamingV2 f they are SVF1, or is it not possible to load SVF1 in streamingV2?

Comment: Looking at the bubblenodes as they are being fed to loadDocumentNode, the first one loads correctly (and is SVF2). The second one is also SVF2 (.isSVF2() returns true) but gets the forbidden 403. There is no difference permission-wise (they are placed at the same place on ACC)

Comment: "They are 3D DWGs" Definitely, the 3D views are SVF2. For ACC/BIM360 files, both  `derivativeV2` and `streamingV2` should work, since ACC/BIM360 translates SVF & SVF2 for the supported file formats (RVT, NWD/NWC, IFC, DWG, etc.), but what is your env, `AutodeskProduction` vs `AutodeskProduction2`?  For `{env: 'AutodeskProduction', api: 'derivativeV2'}`, the model will be loaded as SVF. For  For `{env: 'AutodeskProduction2', api: 'streamingV2'}, it will be SVF2.

Comment: We can discuss this in another thread. Please contact us via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, another official support channel like here.